# Dygraphs StackedBarChart with Multiple Line Series

Tags: dygraphs

We are looking for a Graph similar where we can plot StackedBarChart with multiple line series. This chart is available in Dygraphs for R.
[image: StackedBardChartwithLine]
Is this available in Dygraphs for JS? Can someone help?

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: This is not the site to ask for a library, I'm afraid. Try somewhere else.

Comment: Dear M. Prokhorov, i have asked here if anyone has used custom plotter and did similar work or having idea, how this can be done.  As Dygraphs is very customizable.

Answer (score 1):

dygraphs for R is using dygraphs JS under the hood, so it's definitely possible. You'll want to set a custom plotter for the series you want rendered as bar charts.

```
g = new Dygraph(div, data,
        {
          labels: ['Date', 'A', 'B'],
          series: {
            "A": {
              strokeWidth: 2
            },
            "B": {
              plotter: barChartPlotter
            }
          }
        });
```

You can find a fully-worked example on the [plotters](http://dygraphs.com/tests/plotters.html) demo page.

Comment: Dear Danvk, Thanks your very much for pointing out in the right direction. Will check.